# The time cost with Multithread to calculate Matrix product

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

I am recently learning thread. And in a little experiment I use pthread to try multithread to calculate the product of two matrix. Then I found that using multithread costs even more time than not to. I have tried to enlarge the volume of the matrix, single thread just performs better.
Here are my test code and the results:
Single Thread:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define M 3
#define K 2
#define N 3
int A[M][K]={{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}};
int B[K][N]={{8,7,6},{5,4,3}};
int C[M][N];
int main()
{
int begin = clock();
int result = 0;
int i,j,m;
for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        for(m=0;m<K;m++){
        result+=A[i][m]*B[m][j];
}
C[i][j]=result;
result = 0;
}
int end = clock();
printf("time cost:%d\n",end-begin);
for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

result:

time cost:1
28 23 18 
41 34 27 
54 45 36 
Multithread:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define M 3
#define K 2
#define N 3

/*structure for passing data to thread*/
struct v
{
    int i;
    /*row*/
    int j;
    /*column*/
};
void create_and_pass(struct v *data);
void* runner(void *param);
int A[M][K]={{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}};
int B[K][N]={{8,7,6},{5,4,3}};
int C[M][N];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
/*We have to create M*N worker threads*/
    int begin = clock();
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        struct v *data = (struct v *)malloc(sizeof(struct v));
        data->i=i;
        data->j=j;
        /*Now create the thread passing it data as a parameter*/
        create_and_pass(data);
    }
    int end = clock();
    printf("花费时间:%d\n",end-begin);
        for(i=0;i<M;i++){
            for(j=0;j<N;j++){
                printf("%d ",C[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
void create_and_pass(struct v *data)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,(void *)data);
    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
}
void* runner(void *param)
{
    struct v *data = param;
    int result = 0;
    int m;
    for(m=0;m<K;m++)
        result+=A[data->i][m]*B[m][data->j];
    C[data->i][data->j]=result;
}
```

result:
time cost:1163
28 23 18 
41 34 27 
54 45 36

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a language tag, it might help your question to be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thread creates and starts the worker thread, and immediately joins it. Joining is blocking operation, meaning that no other thread is started until this one finishes. Effectively the execution is sequential, with all the overhead of memory allocation, thread creation, etc.

It is also unlikely that you see any gain on such a small data set.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So how large should the data set be? Any chance I can get a basic range to see the difference? Or should I just have to change the algorithm of pthread calling?